# Using Salt in AES in C# and PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption, mono, aes

I'm trying to encode and decode a string using AES. At the moment, I'm encoding the string in Mono C# using the highest-rated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549775/simple-encryption-algorithm-in-c-net), because `System.Security.Crytpography.Aes` is not available in Mono. However, this implementation uses a Salt, and the [PHP method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php) I'm using to decrypt it does not take a salt, only an Initialization Vector, which I generate.

**My problem:** The encrypted data is salted, and I don't know how to un-salt it even with the known salt string.

1. Should I try to remove the salt from the C# class?

   - Is the implementation good enough using only the plaintext, password/key, and initialization vector?
2. Or is there another form of decryption that I can use in PHP that will take ciphertext, key, salt, and initialization vector?
3. Or should I try to un-salt the decrypted text after calling `mcrypt_decrypt` on it? Is that the right order of things?
4. Or should I rewrite the C# AES class completely? Is it actually a bad example?
5. [edit] Or does anyone know of a `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` implementation I can use in PHP? I'm not sure I'm confident enough to write the implementation myself, lest I completely defeat the point of security through some error.

Sorry for my ignorance, this is the first time I've ever dealt with encryption, and there's a lot of information to take in.

Comment: It's not possible to unsalt something. You have to recreate the same key derivation code in PHP. Hint: it's probably PBKDF2. You have to ask yourself whether you need a password-based solution or a key-based solution.

Comment: So after reading that code closer, what I'd have to do is derive a new set of bytes to use as the decryption key from the original password/key and the salt? Do I have that right? Which means that I'd still need to implement `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` in PHP as stated in @Ospho's answer, I assume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer [you have posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17549863/617485) implements the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` class to get the bytes of the encrypting key. [This is advised, but not mandatory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659214/why-do-i-need-to-use-the-rfc2898derivebytes-class-in-net-instead-of-directly). You don't have to use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` and can simply modify that AES implementation not to take a salt and simply take the password's bytes as the key directly. Although I don't recommend this in practice.

What I do recommend is finding a more suitable PHP AES implementation that allows salting of your password to get the key bytes - which should be available (sorry but I have little experience with PHP to aid you in this; you may find that an additional method exists in the PHP crypto libraries to form a key based on a password and salt input similar to .NET/MONO's `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`).

Comment: I would like to help out. Is Rfc2898DeriveBytes just 1000 iterations with the salt using sha1?  I would post some php code but I have no way of testing it is giving the correct results and I cant find an online implementation to test with.  Is there any test data?

Comment: I ended up going with phpseclib and it works great. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

#1 No

#2 Yes (See below)

#3 No

#4 No, it looks fine to me

#5 Please try this PHP implementation with your encrypted data.  I haven't tested it.

```
<?php

function pbkdf2( $p, $s, $c, $kl, $a = 'sha1' ) {
    $hl = strlen(hash($a, null, true)); # Hash length
    $kb = ceil($kl / $hl);              # Key blocks to compute
    $dk = '';                           # Derived key
    # Create key
    for ( $block = 1; $block <= $kb; $block ++ ) {
        # Initial hash for this block
        $ib = $b = hash_hmac($a, $s . pack('N', $block), $p, true);
        # Perform block iterations
        for ( $i = 1; $i < $c; $i ++ )
            # XOR each iterate
            $ib ^= ($b = hash_hmac($a, $b, $p, true));
        $dk .= $ib; # Append iterated block
    }
    # Return derived key of correct length
    return substr($dk, 0, $kl);
}

//Usage example (Decryption by PHP)
$ciphertext_b64 = "owiCMbopBmr+NvjBEUT2Hg==";

$password = "password";
$salt = "g46dzQ80"; //Please change to the salt you are using.  Copied from the referenced answer code.

//This is the key derivation part.  I think .net uses 1000 iterations of sha1.
$key = pbkdf2($password, $salt, 1000, 32, "sha1");
$iv = "OFRna74m*aze01xY"; //Again, I copied the IV from the .NET code in the answer you referenced.

$plaintext = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($ciphertext_b64), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv), "\0");

echo $plaintext;
// Output = hello
```