# Encrypt/Decrypt word,excel or pdf in c#

Tags: c#, encryption

I am new here so please forgive me for any mistakes. I have a requirement where i have to encrypt the original file and when i do decryption at that time i cannot not save decrypted data into any file. The decrypted data must be loaded in memory and should be shown from there only. If the file word document then it show be shown in the word control and if file is the pdf and then it should be shown in the pdf control.

Please need help for this.

Comment: Let's start with what you tried?

Comment: Thank You for replying chris. I have not tried anything yet. searching since 3 to 4 hours but getting only one library name which is Spire.Doc but it requires to save the file to decrypted and that i can't do as per my requirement.

Comment: This will get you started.  Then try something and post code for what you have tried.  Note that this was the first hit when I searched C# encryption on StackOverflow.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/212707/2270839

Comment: Kevin thankx for replying but i want to encrypt/decrypt file not the text value.

Comment: Ravi - put some effort in. This is straight from Google. Surely you can amend this to suit your needs ? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307010