# encrypting a copy of a text file in c# (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, file, copy, duplicates

I'm working on an encryption program in C# (Windows Forms) and one of the options I'd like to add is that the user will be able to choose an existing text (.txt) file, and the program would make a new file which is the file chosen, but encrypted (without making any changes in the original file).
I though about making a copy of the original file and then encrypting the new file, but I have no clue how to do it.
Please tell me how to do it.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What have you tried..? there are so many options / approaches one could take to do this.. Have you researched what type of encryption you want to use..? please show what you have done thus far if anything at all

Comment: Explain clearly what you need - guidance on encryption or file handling?

Comment: I know how to make a button which opens a browser and lets the user choose the file. I also know how to encrypt the chosen file. What I don't know is how do I make the program create a new file, which is exactly the same as the chosen file, encrypt it (No help needed in that step) and then save it in a directory chosen by the user. By the way, I haven't written my code yet, I'm just practicing using a simple substitution cipher...

Comment: So what's the problem, when using StreamWriter? I have updated my answer. It describes how to chose your save location and how to write the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StreamReader/StreamWriter for loading and saving the file.
**StreamReader:**

```
string unencryptedText;
    private void ReadTextFile()
    {

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
        {
            unencryptedText= reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

**StreamWriter**

```
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("encryptedFile.txt", true))
    {
        writer.Write(encryptedText);
    }
```

Encryption: [Simple insecure two-way "obfuscation" for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165808/simple-2-way-encryption-for-c-sharp)

**Update**
Chose Directory where to save encrypted file(only Directory)

```
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) 
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fbd.SelectedPath+"\\encryptedFile.txt", true))
            {
                writer.Write(encryptedText);
            }
        }
```

Chose Directory and FileName

```
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName, true))
            {
                writer.Write(encryptedText);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Link only answers should be avoided if possible, if the links break then your answer does not answer the question

Comment: Sure, sorry for that. Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Use System.IO.StreamReader and System.IO.StreamWriter to read and write from text files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx

```
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            fileContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        string encryptedContents = Encrypt(fileContents);

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(destinationPath))
        {
            sw.Write(encryptedContents);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File.Copy(pathX,pathY)
```

Will copy the file from path X to path Y.

The next thing is to write the encrypted text to the copied file:

```
File.WriteAllText(pathY,textToWrite)
```

I can also say you will learn more if you read msdn examples. 
Everything you look for is there.