# Cryptographic Exception Caught : Padding is invalid and cannot be removed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, aes

I have Googled and looked on SOF for a solution but sadly I'm a little confused on how to resolve this issue,

For Encryption I'm using the following

[Simple insecure two-way "obfuscation" for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165808/simple-two-way-encryption-for-c-sharp)

The way I use this the end user choose a category and saves the item, on returning from the DB I select the relevant view to be display.

The view name is then Encrypted and passed to a new action.

Within this Action I then try to decrypt the encrypted view name and pass it to the view to be rendered but when I try to decrypt it I get this error mentioned above, I'm uncertain on how to fix this.

My controller looks like this

```
             return RedirectToAction("Description", "Advert", new{
                        encryptedView = crypto.Encrypt(advertModel.View),
                    });
```

which passes the following encryption

```
too8kmao3odfbwbhlaod1w==
```

I then try the following in the action its been redirected to

```
var decryptView = new Crypto().Decrypt("too8kmao3odfbwbhlaod1w==");
```

yet with no avail.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the solution as im using a nuget LowercaseRoutesMVC when I encrypt it, it looks like this

Too8KMao3ODfBWBHLaoD1w==

When I try to decrypt its lower case as mentioned above which is what causes the issue.

I'll have to think of another way to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. You can leave the question and answer and accept the answer after a while. It seems that this is an issue that is easily configurable in the framework so maybe others get caught in the same trap.