# ASP.NET 5 Creating RSA key,

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, rsa

I'm trying to create WebApi with token-based authentication in my ASP.NET 5 app. I'm following these steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/29698502/2420851 .
But I'm stuck already at the first one with creating RSA key.

Line `RSACryptoServiceProvider myRSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);`

produces compilation error `The type 'RSACryptoServiceProvider' exists in both 'System.Security.Cryptography.Csp'  and 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSA'`

when I add `"System.Security.Cryptography.RSA": "4.0.0-beta-22819"` to my `project.json` error message just changes to `The type 'RSACryptoServiceProvider' exists in both 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSA' and 'mscorlib'`

Namespaces `System.Security.Cryptography.RSA` and `System.Security.Cryptography.Csp` are both unavailable.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated

Do like this:

`System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider myRSA = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);`

or you have to remove the colliding imported namespaces and only have
the "using System.Security.Cryptography"

If you are using ASP.NET 5 Core then you need to check this question
on how to get Crypt to work:

[Which encryption algorithm do we use in Asp.net 5 Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27884517/2827823)

or remove "dnxcore50" from your project.

Comment: I have only ``using System.Security.Cryptography;``.


``Csp`` and ``RSA`` are not availiable... maybe I'm missing some dependency

Comment: Did an update of my answer .. does it solve it for you?

Comment: No, i tried this before. However I solved the problem. It was about .NET Core, I removed dnxcore50 from project.json and it worked. Thanks anyway

Comment: Just found out that myself .. updated my answer accordingly