# How to encrypt Model values in RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, encryption

How do I encrypt and decrypt Model values that are passed using `RedirectToAction`

```
public ActionResult CustomerDetails(CustomerModel model)
  {
        return RedirectToAction("ConfirmDetails", model);
  }
```

I want to encrypt all values in the model and decrypt them in `ConfirmDetails` method.

Comment: What is the it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The model values are passed within the URL and are visible, I want them hidden.

Comment: check this out. http://madskristensen.net/post/httpmodule-for-query-string-encryption . I myself used this to resolve the exact same issue as you have mentioned here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/212707/5745152) decrypt and encrypt method myself, and it works perfect. You can do anything with the output.

**Note: read the post and do what he says.**

To run the encryption:

> Using it is easy: just instantiate the class and then call `EncryptToString(string StringToEncrypt)` and `DecryptString(string StringToDecrypt)` as methods. It couldn't be any easier (or more secure) once you have this class in place.

In your case it would be:

```
SimpleAES SEAS = new SimpleAES();
string decryptedstring = SEAS.EncryptToString(model.modelitem);
```

To decrypt the encrypted string:

```
SimpleAES SEAS = new SimpleAES();
string encryptedstring = SEAS.DecryptString(model.modelitem);
```

---

**EDIT |** Just to pass all model items in:

```
List<string> EncryptedValues = new List<string>();
SimpleAES SEAS = new SimpleAES();
foreach(var modelitem in model)
{
     EncryptedValues.Add(SEAS.EncryptToString(Convert.ToString(modelitem)));
}

// Do something with the list.
```

Comment: This means, I have to encrypt and decrypt every value in the model. I was looking for a away to just encrypt the model object like this `Encrypt(model)`

Comment: I have 10 model values of strings and dates.

Comment: @Angwenyi See edited answer. NOTE: be sure to convert the datetime to string! You need to have strings only! It can't convert the datetime property.

Comment: @Angwenyi, is this not the method you are looking for?